# How to prevent "Switch User Account" in Ubuntu 12.04 from logging me out?

Tags: 12.04, switch-user

The title of the feature, "Switch User Account", suggests that the current user's information is safe and can be restored. However, when I log back in to my account after a "Switch User Account", my session starts fresh.

How can I keep my original session running when the user is switched?

This [has been asked for Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412174/does-switch-account-in-ubuntu-13-04-logs-out-the-first-account-upon-switching) but no answer was provided there. I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

UPDATE: Please note that I am not looking for a better way to "Switch User". I just want that when I accidentally do "Switch User" from the menu, I am not logged out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in terminal to switch user without logging-off :

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

Try it and reply .

Comment: This will not switch users. this command will just switch to lightdm login window.

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to "Switch User". I end up hitting it accidentally in hurriedly trying to bring up the calendar by clicking on the "Date and Time" widget next to the "User Accounts" widget. So, I just want that "Switch User", as in the menu, not perform the same functionality as "Log Out".

Comment: switch user should not logoff your user .

Comment: What to do if it is logging me out?

Comment: did you try this command and log to the second user

Comment: Just did. I logged myself back in at the screen and got a fresh session.

Comment: what desktop environment you are using kdm gdm openbox ?

Comment: I am using the default one, Unity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13385/discussion-between-wsaleem-and-nux)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
  switch-to-user USERNAME [SESSION]
```

This will switch to a user session(Replace USERNAME with yours)

`dm-tool --help` shows these options:

```
  switch-to-greeter                   Switch to the greeter
  switch-to-user USERNAME [SESSION]   Switch to a user session
  switch-to-guest [SESSION]           Switch to a guest session
  lock                                Lock the current seat
  list-seats                          List the active seats
  add-nested-seat                     Start a nested display
  add-local-x-seat DISPLAY_NUMBER     Add a local X seat
  add-seat TYPE [NAME=VALUE...]       Add a dynamic seat
```

Comment: Thanks. I added an update to my original post to better explain my problem. As I commented on nux's answer above, I am not looking for a better way to "Swtich User". I just want the menu's "Swtich User" to not log me out.